# Bluetooth Problem With Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: bluetooth, internet, 20.04

When i activate bluetooth, internet connection slow down.
Can anyone help?

```
$lsb_release -d ; lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
```

```
$ls /etc/modprobe.d/
alsa-base.conf                  blacklist-bcm43.conf     blacklist-framebuffer.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf     iwlwifi.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist.conf           blacklist-modem.conf        dkms.conf                       iwlwifi-opt.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          blacklist-firewire.conf  blacklist-oss.conf          intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
```

Comment: Hello ! Please edit your post with the folllowing command in your terminal, therefore you'll give use some information about your system : `lsb_release -d ; lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

Comment: What the result of `ls /etc/modprobe.d/` ? same, **EDIT** your question (en delete the comment just above, as well as your answer just below)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Wi-Fi 2.4 GHz and bluetooth share the same radio frequency.

Also the 2.4 range is very crowded nowadays.

The Wi-Fi driver has to slow down transmission while sending something using Bluetooth.

The solution is to use the 5 GHz wireless.

Comment: How can i change that?

Comment: Change what? Switch to 5 GHz? You need to have a 5 GHz capable access point.

Comment: Any other option?

Comment: I am not aware of anything with this hardware. It is 5 GHz capable. But you can't tune 2.4 anyway.