# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi becomes very slow when bluetooth headphones connected (Qualcomm Atheros)

Tags: 20.04

Wifi almost stops working when I have bluetooth headphones connected (Bose QC 35).

Anyone else experiencing this? Any suggested solutions?

Tried methods that reported the some problem in 18.04, but none working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243071/bluetooth-problem-with-ubuntu-20-04lts), it seems to be an interference as The WiFi 2.4 GHz and bluetooth shares the same frequency. Of course, This problem didn't happend to me when I was on Windows (Or, at least, I didn't notice). Try to check If you can configure your router to use 5 Ghz Wireless band.